# Kohana/PHP - Defining ORM relationship for the 'favorites' table

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3.3

I have 3 tables in the following format.

- **users**

id

FirstName

LastName

- **userjobs**

id

jobinfo

- **starredjobs**

id

user_id

userjob_id

comments

enddate

The 'starredjobs'  table holds all the jobs which an user starred/added to favorites. 
I have defined the following relationships in their respective model files.

- user.php

> protected $_has_many = array( 'starredjobs' => array('model' => 'starredjobs' , 'foreign_key'=>'user_id'),

- starredjob.php

  > protected $_belongs_to = array('user' => array('model' => 'user','foreign_key' => 'user_id'));
  >
  > protected $_has_many = array('jobs' => array('model'=> 'userjob', 'foreign_key'=> 'job_id'));
- userjobs.php

  > none

The idea is to retrieve all the starred jobs and details regarding jobs from the user object. A user can 'n' number of jobs and  A job can be starred by 'n' number of users.

Am i defining relationships correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No. What you have here is a typical `n:m` relationship which can easily be used in Kohana using [has_many "through"](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm/relationships#hasmany-through) (as is used in the default roles users-relationship). But this doesn't allow for extra attributes in the "middle" table, so you need to use 2 [has_many](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm/relationships#hasmany) with corresponding [belongs_to](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm/relationships#belongsto).

This can be described in plain English like so:

- One `user` has many `starredjobs`.
- One `job` has many `starredjobs`.
- One `starredjob` belongs to one `user` and one `job`

Also consider the difference between `far_key` and `foreign_key` (official doc sadly doesn't cover it), but one easy rule to remember: The key in the other table is far away -> it is the `far_key`.

This would give you the following

**user.php**

```
$_has_many = array(
    'starredjobs' => array(
        'model' => 'Starredjob',
        'far_key' => 'user_id'
    )
);
```

**userjob.php**

```
$_has_many = array(
    'starredbyuser' => array(
        'model' => 'Starredjob',
        'far_key' => 'userjob_id'
    )
);
```

**starredjob.php**

```
$_belongs_to = array(
    'user' => array(
        'model' => 'User',
        'foreign_key' => 'user_id'
    ),
    'job' => array(
        'model' => 'Userjob',
        'foreign_key' => 'userjob_id'
    )
);
```

Now you can do various things such as:

```
//get all jobs starred by given $user
foreach ($user->starredjobs->find_all() as $starredjob) {
    //info on userjob via $starredjob->job->jobinfo, etc.
    //info from pivot table via $starredjob->comments, etc.
}

//get all users that starred a given $userjob
foreach ($userjob->starredbyuser->find_all() as $starredjob) {
    //info on user via $starredjob->user->FirstName, etc.
    //info from pivot table via $starredjob->comments, etc.
}
```